# I was analyzing the aggregate report ..where i see that maximum time took too high than 99 percentile . where server side cpu utilization was ok

Tags: testing, jmeter, load

i have to load testing of the web application . there were approx 10 different HTTPS requests .
Executed script for 30 minute duration. and script executed properly without any error .
I was analyzing the aggregate report ..where i see that maximum time took too high than 99 percentile ..it mean only 1 user took too much type.
and server side there was average load like CPU utilization of application was 45% and CPU utilization of DB instance was very low approx 8 %
I could not understand that then why maximum time was too high .. but 99 percentile was OK
[image]

Answer (score 1):

CPU or memory usage doesn't necessary need to be high in order to explain high response times, it might be the case the application doesn't fully utilize the underlying hardware resources due to inappropriate configuration or inefficient coding algorithms. Or caused by a [slow SQL query](https://orangematter.solarwinds.com/2018/01/17/slow-queries-move-fast-to-fix-them/)

The only way to determine what application has been doing is looking at some form of an [APM tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) or a [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools)

It might also be the case JMeter itself is a problem because you're violating minimum 3 [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

1. You're using too many listeners in our test plan and you're supposed to use 0 as [Listeners don't add any value and just consume valuable resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing)
2. You're running your test in GUI mode which is supposed to be used only for tests development and/or debugging, when it comes to execution [you should be running the test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
3. You're not using [the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version)